# Is there any way to set SVN path read permissions on Scm-Manager

Tags: authorization, user-permissions, scmmanager

I had been using VisualSvn Server for a long time. I was able to set user access read/write permissions for each folder of the repo with VSS.

I couldn't find a way to do that on SCM-Manager. There is a Path Write Protection plugin, but I think it is just for write permissions. I want users to be able to reach or not   specific paths on the repo.

Is there a way to do that with SCM-Manager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, there is no such option and we do not plan this for the future. We suggest using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals) for this.

Comment: That is sad :(  Could you give a bit more details about "submodules"  ? I haven't heard about the submodules concept on SVN.

Comment: Sorry, I will always mix those. I meant externals, thx @f10sh for the correction!